# Why set attribute is not working in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Code1:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="test"></div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var y = document.createTextNode("This is a span element.");
  var x = document.createElement("SPAN");
 x.appendChild(y);

document.getElementById("test").appendChild(x).setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;"); 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Code 2:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var y = document.createTextNode("This is a span element.");
  var x = document.createElement("SPAN").appendChild(y);

document.getElementById("test").appendChild(x).setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;"); 
}
</script>
```

Why attribute is not setting for span? In code 1 I am getting required output ie red background for text but in code 2 it seems I am not getting that.

Just want to write whole script in one line.

Comment: The return value of `appendChild` is the appended child node. In code 2, `x` is a text node, not a `span`.

Comment: `x` is a text node and you can't call `setAttibute(...)` on a text node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) returns the appended child, not the parent. Hence

```
var x = document.createElement("SPAN").appendChild(y);
```

is the same as

```
var x = y;
```

Since `x` (and `y`) refer to a `TextNode`, setting an attribute on them won't have any effect (only elements can have attributes).

---

> Just want to write whole script in one line.

That's unnecessary, however, you can put as many statements in a line as you want, as long as they are separated be `;`.